Missing FastReport pas files. I now cannot compile my old Delphi project using frxClass, frxExportBaseDialog, frxDBSet I only have hpp files
I installed the newest Delphi 12-Athens and the components.
Using GitIt I installed also FastReports.
the components are correctly installed, so I can put them on a form and the corresponding units are added to the uses, but when I compile the project I get then next error (depending on what the first unit is that is in the uses):

[dcc32 Fatal Error] FrmOrderBeheer.pas(17): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'frxClass'

The frxClass.dcu and frxClass.hpp are on my computer, but nog frxClass.pas.
I have only Delphi, no C++.
I also downloaded the FastReports version from their website (frvcl_all_rad.exe), but also in that package the same files exists.
Can anyone help me?

Have you checked if the directory where is the "frxClass.dcu" file is in the Library path ?

@MJKing yes in Tools, Options, Language, Delphi, Library, Library path stands:
$(BDSCatalogRepository)\FastReport-2023.3\RS29\VCL\Win32\

my solution:  install Fast Reports via GETIT, run Delphi in Admin Mode
and yes, correct lib path settings are essential

Finally I found the problem.
In my .dproj file the next line was responsible for the problem:

<DCC_UnitSearchPath>C:\Program Files
(x86)\FastReports\LibD24;C:_Source\Gerp\DataSetConverter4Delphi\src;$(DCC_UnitSearchPath)</DCC_UnitSearchPath>

After I deleted:
C:\Program Files (x86)\FastReports\LibD24;
the problem was solved.
